# Max number of elements for +(id)arrayWithObjects:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, llvm

I have a problem with this statement: `self.arraySpec = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"ALZ", @"Area", @"BST", @"CSO", @"GLL", "GNO", "LGO", @"PAS", @"PLE", @"PTA", @"PZA", @"RIP", @"SDA", @"VIA", @"VLE", @"VLO", nil];`
With the hybrid compiler the apps freeze, instead pure llvm show a bad access.
There's something I need to know about it?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're seeing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"GNO"?? "LGO"?? I think you need to check your syntax, you appear to be missing some @ symbols!